# Why is this instance of dynamic allocation not successful?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, cout, pow

I am trying to create a program that raises 10 to the power of the index number (1 for index 0, 10 for index 1, 100 for index 2, etc.). When I run this program, it does not output anything.  What is the issue?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int* powersOfTwo(int n);

int* powersOfTwo(int n)
{
    int i, x=10;
    n=3;
    
    int *arr = new int(n);
    
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        
        arr[i]=pow(x, i);
        
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        
    }



    return 0;

}



int main() {

    powersOfTwo;

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int int(n)` isnt' the same as `new int[n]`.  Also, you'll go out of bounds in your array access even after fixing this bug.

Comment: `new int(n)` allocates a single `int` with the value `n`.  `new int[n]` allocates an array of size `n`.

Comment: Changing the parentheses to brackets did not seem to help.  Are there any other issues?

Comment: `powersOfTwo;` ? Does that even compile ? if it does then `n` inside the function is undefined - you may be lucky and it's getting a value of 0. Returns in `int*` but you only ever return 0.

Comment: `for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {` if you allow `n` better make the array have n+1 elements instead of n

Comment: @John3136 `powerOfTwo;` evaluates to the function, and the result is discarded. It doesn't do anything, but it compiles. And `0` will return an `int*` null pointer value.

Comment: You may get a warning about code that has no effect.

Comment: You're not even calling your function.  What book are you learning C++ from?

Comment: What edits do I need to make to keep it from returning a null value?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sure - but I'd expect a modern compiler to complain about it.

Comment: Replace `pow(x,2)` with `(x * x)`.  The `pow` function is for floating point and multiplication is much faster and simpler.

Comment: To do 2 to a power, use bit shifting: `(1 << n)` will raise 2 to the power of `n`.

Comment: I don't want to square x, though.  I need to raise it to the power of i.

Comment: @John3136 Compilers generally only identify the most frequently encountered dead code. It is a hard problem in general with low payout, so there hasn't been a lot of effort put into that. Static analysis tools already do a good job of that, so there isn't much motivation to have compilers be better at it.

Comment: To call a function, you need to supply a parameter list, even if it is empty.  In your `main` function, try `powersOfTwo(5)`.

Comment: @W.W.Atkinson C++ cannot really be self taught. It has the concept of Undefined Behavior. That means it is impossible to learn by trial and observation. The behavior you see could be standard behavior, or it could be the result of Undefined Behavior. You have no way of knowing without looking up everything with an authoritative source. You need a good book or some sort of equivalent resource to learn C++.

Comment: Since you are self-taught, disregard anything you learned about dynamic memory allocation.  Use `std::vector`, it can be passed by reference.

Comment: @François Andrieux yep - just tested on an ancient solaris box - Solaris CC doesn't flag it even with +w2 (highest warning level I could find from a quick scan on the manual).. g++ -Wall does flag it (even the ancient Solaris version I tried)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I just like to say that I disagree with this. It's true that you can't learn the standards perfectly from experimenting with code on a certain compiler - but in practice if you're learning it's fine. You might make some wrong assumptions, but you'll do that anyway even if you're learning "text book style." Personally I think that the best learning is through tackling interesting problems (for the learner), then later being exposed to some new syntax/ideas/standards, etc, then repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do the operation in a loop without calling `pow`:

```
void powerOfTwo(std::vector<int>& powers, int quantity)
{
  int power = 1;
  powers.push_back(power);
  for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
  {
    power = power * 10;
    powers.push_back(power);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> database;
  powersOfTwo(database, 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
     std::cout << " " << database[i];
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. The vector is passed by reference, so it can be modified.
2. There is no forced dynamic memory allocation; no leaks.
3. The vector will expand as necessary.
4. The power of 10 will be calculated, by mathematical definition of *power* or exponentiation.
5. No calls to `power`; all integer arithmetic.